# Grails won't display images in subfolder using tag

Tags: grails, resources

I have image files in Grails project such as:

```
grails-app/assets/images/admin/img1.jpg
```

I am trying to display it as:

```
<g:img dir="images/admin" file="img1.jpg">
```

In development environment (Grails 2.4), it is not showing up. I get 404. However, if I copy the image in:

```
grails-app/assets/images/img1.jpg
```

and change code like below:

```
<g:img dir="images" file="img1.jpg">
```

it works.

Plugin I am using:

```
build ":tomcat:7.0.55"
// plugins for the compile step
compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
compile ':cache:1.1.8'
compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

// plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
```

Comment: Have you tried this `<asset:image src="images/admin/img1.jpg" />`?

Comment: @Abs Yes, after your comment, I tried that. It is now trying to access the image using path like: /grails-app/assets/images/admin/img1.jpg and again throwing 404

Comment: Asset pipeline search image in asset folder by default as it uses asset pipe-line plugin, If you want use it as you mentioned in the question, you should use resource plugin.

Comment: @user1791574 I want to use asset pipeline plugin. So the issue remains is how I can access images for configuration in OP.

Answer (score 6):

From what I can see Abs was very close try.

```
 <asset:image src="admin/img1.jpg" />
```

If you refer to:

http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html

under 4.3:

Assets can also be referenced within subdirectories if required and simply require the use of the relative path.

```
<asset:image src="icons/delete.png"/>
```

so their already in images and have a folder called icons

You should also be able to do something similar with alternative method:

```
<img src="${assetPath(src: 'admin/img1.jpg')}"/>
<g:img src="${assetPath(src: 'admin/img1.jpg')}"/>
```